# How to partition by and then order by random in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to partition a customer sample set by region and marketplace using Spark SQL, but in the partition result, I would like to select a random 100,000 users that was returned.

Is there a way to use `random()` in `partition by order by` clause in Spark SQL? The code below using `random()` always returns error, but without `random()`, it works perfect. Thank you in advance for your answers!

```
customer_panel_s3_location = f"s3://my-bucket/region_id={region_id}/marketplace_id={marketplace_id}/"
customer_panel_table = spark.read.parquet(customer_panel_s3_location)
customer_panel_table.createOrReplaceTempView("customer_panel")
dataset_date = '2023-03-16'
customer_sample_size = 100000
partition_customers_by = 'region_id, marketplace_id'

# The code below returns an error 
customer_panel_df = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        , row_number() over (partition by {partition_customers_by} order by random()) AS rn
        FROM
          customer_panel AS c
        WHERE
          c.target_date < CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE)
          AND c.target_date >= date_sub(CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE), 7)
        ) t
    WHERE t.rn <= bigint({customer_sample_size})
""")

# But after removing 'random()', it works
customer_panel_df = spark.sql(f"""
        SELECT *
        , row_number() over (partition by {partition_customers_by} order by {partition_customers_by}) AS rn
        FROM
          customer_panel AS c
        WHERE
          c.target_date < CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE)
          AND c.target_date >= date_sub(CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE), 7)
""")

print(f"Row count of {table_name}: {customer_panel_df.count():,}")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to use `random()` function within the ORDER BY clause of a window function `row_number()` in Spark SQL. This is because `random()` generates a non-deterministic value, meaning that it can produce different results for the same input parameters.
One potential solution to achieve the desired outcome is to use the `rand()` function instead of `random()`. The `rand()` function generates a deterministic value based on the seed value, which can be set using the `spark.sql.functions.rand(seed)` function.

Comment: Thank you, @DipanjanMallick! Using `row_number() over (partition by {partition_customers_by} order by rand(420)) AS rn` works like a charm! I wish you wrote your response as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Adding the comment to answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use `random()` function within the ORDER BY clause of a window function `row_number()` in Spark SQL. This is because `random()` generates a non-deterministic value, meaning that it can produce different results for the same input parameters.

One potential solution to achieve the desired outcome is to use the `rand()` function instead of `random()`. The `rand()` function generates a deterministic value based on the seed value, which can be set using the `spark.sql.functions.rand(seed)` function.

Below is the implementation of the same to select a random subset of customers from each partition:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

customer_panel_df = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            row_number() over (partition by {partition_customers_by} order by rand({seed})) AS rn
        FROM customer_panel AS c
        WHERE c.target_date < CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE)
          AND c.target_date >= date_sub(CAST('{dataset_date}' AS DATE), 7)
        ) t
    WHERE t.rn <= {customer_sample_size}
""")
```

Please note that the `rand()` function takes a seed value as an argument, which ensures that the function returns a deterministic value for each partition.
You may choose any integer value per your use case as the seed.

Comment: Thank you, @DipanjanMallick! Accepted the answer because it works. :) I also have posted another [pyspark related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75770629/1330974) in case you have some spare time to take a look. Thank you again and I'm learning something new about pyspark everyday. :)